# Manage SM Dynamic Slideshow slider effects

Tags: magento, slider, magento-1.8

hi am using [SM Dynamic Slideshow](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sm-dynamic-slideshow-responsive-module.html) and i need to change the effects of slider. Now some random effect is coming on each slide. i need one effect for all slides. please help.

thank you.

i got my answer. here is the sc of the back end admin panel :) thank you for the help .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento backend, go to `product selection` of SM Dynamic Slideshow an give all your slides the same `data-easing` property, e.g.: `easeOutExpo`.

More about easing effects possibilities: http://jqueryui.com/easing/

Comment: one more doubt, can i add fadeIn effect and fadeOut for slides??

Comment: You can use jquery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` function to do this.